# Check if path on a remote server exists

Tags: php

Do you know how to manage that? I know that one can specify a context using the `mkdir` function, but using this function I cannot check if the path is existing, can't I?

EDIT:

FTP connection to the server is established.

Comment: If you are talking about remote server then you need either to get access via SSH on it and execute commands or use any server side API. If the server did not configure or explicitly disabled directory browsing etc, then you are out of luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `file_exists`. http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php

`if (file_exists('path/to/file/or/dir')){
     doSomething();
 } else {
     createFileOrDir();
 }`

For a remote server use:

`is_dir('ftp://user:password@example.com/some/dir/path');`

Comment: I don't think he means a remote server because he wants to use `mkdir`

Comment: You are telling me that you can create directories on a different server with `mkdir`?

Comment: yes, it works. Check http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mkdir.php , http://www.php.net/manual/en/stream.contexts.php and http://www.php.net/manual/en/context.ftp.php .

Comment: With FTP connection. I see you've added that to your question. When the connection is established you could use: http://nl.php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-chdir.php See example #1

Answer (score 1):

You can use `is_dir()` together with the `FTP` protocol. You can test it:

```
var_dump(is_dir('ftp://ftp.debian.org/debian/')); // bool(true)
```

---

However, you cannot do the same with the `HTTP` protocol:

```
var_dump(is_dir('http://ftp.debian.org/debian/')); // bool(false)
```

This is because the HTTP protocol does not provide information about whether the remote *resource* identifies a folder or a file.

---

Update: Is it not fully true that the HTTP protocol does not know about whether the remote resource is a directory or not. There is a special mimetype definition for that, which the server could send along with the Content-Type header, which could be checked by clients:

```
Content-Type: httpd/unix-directory
```

But it is rarely used in the wild. Most web servers disable directory listings at all for security reasons.